# Why i am facing ssl issue for mobile networks?

Tags: security, ssl, networking, https

I have one website deployed on Ubantu droplet for my account. I am having one issue here, when I load on brodband network the site loading correctly. But if I load site on mobile phone or mobile network on laptop then site not loading correctly. What I observed when I load site on brodband it identifies for certificate "app.myithelpline.com" and loads correctly as shown in "good.png" but when I load it on mobile network it checks for "myithelpline.com" as shown in "bad.png". Anyone knows why I am facing this issue?

Not working for this certificate
[image]

Working fine for this certificate
[image]

Comment: Are the Subject Names, Serial Numbers and Public Key Hashes the same in each certificate? You should also state the details of the "mobile network". What device are your using, what version of the OS, and what is the carrier?

Comment: is that the same picture twice?  I'm not seeing a difference in those cert images

Answer (score 0):

No Worries I have fixed this issue. I need to set up ipv6 redirection which fixed my issue. Thanks for help.